# How to put "/b" into regex object?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my code..

```
data.replace( /\bABC\b/g , function(matched) {
    console.log(matched);
})
```

And I would like to make some change like below

```
var regex = new RegExp('\b' + 'ABC' + '\b', 'g');
data.replace( regex , function(matched) {
    console.log(matched);
})
```

However, it seems not working.

How should I do make it work? is problem from `'\b'` position?

Comment: `'\\b' + 'ABC' + '\\b'`

Comment: Yes as @Tushar suggests, now it is in a string, not a Regex construction, you need to escape the backslashes ... with a backslash

Answer (score 1):

Like **@Tushar** mentioned in **[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418304/how-to-put-b-into-regex-object#comment-62342407)** you have to use double backslashes `\\` because backslash made for turning special characters into string characters in javascript, so your code will be like:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + 'ABC' + '\\b', 'g');
data.replace( regex , function(matched) {
    console.log(matched);
})
```

Hope this helps.